# How to allow gfortran "-Werror" character*8 compilation to succeed

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I'd like to do a build with -Werror but not fail for a certain set of problems.

In this case I have the following program to exhibit the feature I'd like to keep on using to include legacy Fortran 77 headers into Fortran 2003 programs:

```
PROGRAM gfortran_charstar
  CHARACTER*8 text
  text = 'aaaa'
  PRINT *, text
END PROGRAM gfortran_charstar
```

Compiling this with

```
$ gfortran -std=f2003 -c -o gfortran-charstar-werror.o gfortran-charstar-werror.f90
```

gives:

```
gfortran-charstar-werror.f90:2.13:

  CHARACTER*8 text
             1
Warning: Obsolescent feature: Old-style character length at (1)
```

and consequently

```
$ gfortran -std=f2003 -Werror -c -o gfortran-charstar-werror.o gfortran-charstar-werror.f90
gfortran-charstar-werror.f90:2.2:

  CHARACTER*8 text
  1
Error: Unclassifiable statement at (1)

gfortran-charstar-werror.f90:3.9:

  text = 'aaaa'
     1
Error: Can't convert CHARACTER(1) to REAL(4) at (1)
```

fails. For other problems I can e.g. use -Wno-error=unused-function to suppress the error fail, but for old-style character length specifications I've found nothing. Is anyone aware of a corresponding flag?

Comment: Do you need to use the `-std=f2003` option?

Comment: I don't see the logic behind forcing 2003 standard and using f77 code together. If you know you are using f77 code, drop std=f2003 part.
You can do it filewise, i.e. compile your old f77 code without f2003, and the part you are developing (in a separate file) with f2003 check

Comment: It is a warning that you are using some old construct. You can ignore that. If you are using `-Werror`, in these circumstances, it is really your problem, not every warning should be treated as a stopper, many can be ignored. Or just use `-std=legacy`.

Comment: The -std=f2003 is for new code that still makes use of the old parts. I don't want to change the old parts to no longer be Fortran 77 and I don't want to make an F2003ized copy because the code is in a common header that is valid Fortran for both versions of the standard. I need -std=f2003 because otherwise I get warnings for the new constructs. I also would like to emphasize that CHARACTER* declarations are still valid Fortran 2003 and obsolescent is not the same as obsolete or deleted.